# how extract the alphanumeric value using regex

Tags: python-3.x

```
import re
text  = """THE PO NUMBER 134314 MUST BE INCLUDED ALONG WITH
SERVICE DATE ON ALL INVOICES SUBMITTED THROUGH THE AVID BILL PAY PROCESS.
THANK YOU."""

p_no = re.search("PO# (\w+)|PO NUMBER (\w+)", text)
print(p_no)
if p_no == None:
    print("No value found")
else:
    print(p_no.group(1))

REQUIRED SOLUTION : 134314
```

Is there any solution to get the text after PO number but it should also take alphanumeric like B14786,AC7823 etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put `PO#` and `PO NUMBER` in an alternation pattern in a non-capturing group so that there's only one capturing group to deal with and that `p_no.group(1)` will always contain a value no matter which of `PO#` and `PO NUMBER` matches:

```
p_no = re.search(r"(?:PO#|PO NUMBER) (\w+)", text)
```